# Подключение к базе данных MySQL Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Не могу подключиться к *бд*, которая хранится на хостинге.

Появляется ошибка:

> Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

а при подключении к бд которая находится на моем компе все работает:

> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>       СБОРКА УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНА (общее время: 17 секунды)

---

```
package mysql;

import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnect {
    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public DBConnect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql.hostinger.ru:3306/u740438416_test", "u740438416_asd", "asdasd");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а данный хостинг разве поддерживает прямое подключение к БД? я имею ввиду бесплатный тарифный план

Comment: я не знаю, от этого может быть? если знаете подскажите пожалуйста на каком хостинге можно это сделать

Comment: от этого по всей видимости и есть, прослойку на php надо делать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Причин ошибке `Communications link failure` может быть много. Суть в том, что JDBC не может подключиться к этой БД. Проверьте данные БД: URL, порт, сам сервер с БД, настройки БД, Firewall ваш/на сервере и др.

Comment: не подскажите как это можно сделать? просто я новичок) мне задали задание с бд я сделал работает, а сейчас нужно изменить программу так, чтоб бд не хранилась на компе локально

Comment: Для начала прочитайте документацию от вашего хостера. Может он вообще не разрешает подключиться к БД из вне сервера?

Comment: а вы не знакомы с каким либо хостингом к которому есть доступ из вне?

Comment: Возьмите лучше сервер, а не хостинг. И настраивайте все доступы сами.

Comment: это все на ком либо сайте можно почитать узнать? если не сложно подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: На хабре есть статья http://habrahabr.ru/post/111311/ об опыте аренды сервера. В зависимости от операционной системы сервера нагуглите то, как поставить туда Apache и MySQL.

Comment: Если это университетское или школьное задание, то наверняка у кого-то из товарищей есть сервер. Можете попросить воспользоваться его БД.

Comment: да университетское, у меня denwer установлен на компе я делаю все работает, а как в инет выкладываю базу ничего не происходит, я вас не совсем понял по поводу того что у кого то из товарищей есть сервер(

Comment: Вы ведь не единственный человек в группе, кому поручили выполнить такое задание?

Comment: единственный)))

Comment: Ну тогда арендуйте сервер (смотрите статью на хабре) и настраивайте для своих нужд.

Comment: я подключился к бд с платного тарифного плана, подключение проходит успешно, но теперь появилась новая ошибка(( run:
getData Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
СБОРКА УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНА (общее время: 2 секунды)

Comment: Откройте новый тикет. Этот был связан с подключением и вы получили на него ответ. Откройте новый тикет, в котором расскажите больше о возникшей ошибке, с предоставлением кода.

Comment: Ну, или хотя бы обновите тело этого вопроса. Поместите код и расскажите об ошибке.