# Помогите с ошибкой CommunicationsException

Tags: java, jdbc

При подключении к MySQL с помощью JDBC появляется нижеприведенная ошибка. Как её можно исправить?

Сама ошибка:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:
```

Код:

```
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://somehost:3306/db", "login", "password");
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    String query = "select * from players";
    resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);
    while (resultset.next())
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Что то есть");
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "Агась");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "Ошибка загрузки базы: ", e);
}
```

Comment: У вас сервер недоступен. Может вы IP неправильно записали, может на нем порт закрыт. Проверяйте. На ruSO этот вопрос уже задавался  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/455788/197447 Вот более подробный ответ с параллельного сайта http://stackoverflow.com/a/2985169/5694145

Comment: Вы случайно не реальные данные тут опубликовали?

Comment: Вы изначальную причину не указали, приведите полный стектрейс.